# Override provider from peer module in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-module, angular-providers

I have 2 library modules which are defined like this:

```
import { Something} from 'services/Something';
import { SomeComponent} from 'components/SomeComponent';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        SomeComponent,
    ],
    providers: [
        Something,
    ],
    ...
})
export class LibAModule { }



import { Something} from '../services/Something';

@Component({...})
export class SomeComponent {
    public constructor (private readonly _something: Something) { }
}
```

```
import { LibAModule, Something } from 'libraryA';

@NgModule({
    providers: [
        {
            provide: Something,
            useClass: SomethingAwesome,
        }
    ],
    ...
})
export class LibBModule { }
```

Then I have my App Module

```
import { LibAModule } from 'libraryA';
import { LibBModule } from 'libraryB';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        LibAModule,
        LibBModule,
    ],
    ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Using this setup, the component `SomeComponent` will get an instance of `Something` injected.
What I need is that `SomeComponent` gets an instance of `SomethingAwesome` injected without modifying `AppModule`.

When I directly add the override to my App Module, it works and everything in `LibAModule` will get `SomethingAwesome` injected, but I would like to not change AppModule.

Is it possible to change the `LibBModule` in such a way that my `AppModule` will pick up the override without having to add it manually to the `providers` of `AppModule`?

Answer (score 0):

Its really confusing as to what the problem is, when you import any service, you specify the path of the module in the import itself, so there is no way that both will get messed up right? Dependency injection will pickup the correct service using this.

```
import { Something } from 'libraryA';

@Component({
    ....
})
export class App {
    constructor(private something: Something) {}
}
```

Comment: I've added a component declaration to the question which hopefully better explains the problem

Comment: @wertzui please share the imports for the component also, if possible more code

Comment: Ok, I've added the Imports too.

Comment: @wertzui could you share from where you imported `private readonly _something: Something`, I would like the import line for the compoent,  you need to import it like how I shared in the answer

Comment: They are in library A. I've added the imports.